# Subset sum Prob. - Recursive step

Tags: algorithm

This question is about the `Subset Sum problem with positive integers`

Assume that we have n positive integers a[1],a[2],...,a[n] and we are given an Integer M. We want to know if there is a subset of integers with sum M.

Set v[i,m] = 1 if there is a subset of a[1], a[2], ... , a[i] with sum m and v[i,m] = 0 otherwise.

if v[i,m] = 1 it must be either because we can get m just by using the numbers a[1], a[2], ... , a[i-1] or because we can get the sum m - a[i] by using the same numbers. We get the recursion.

- Could someone explain the last paragraph where either the first condition must hold or the second condition must hold if v[i,m] = 1. Is there a proof that either condition must hold?

lets take an example with the n positive integers to be : [3, 2, 7, 1] and M = 6 , then we have a subset [3,2,1]

```
just by using the numbers a[1], a[2], ... , a[i-1]
```

So that means we could remove the integer 1 and so that 3+2=6 , which doesn't hold , so we move on to the next condition:

```
sum m - a[i] by using the same numbers
```

Ofcourse  3+2 = 6-1  - well this condition should always hold.

I am missing something in my understanding of what they are trying to say, could someone fill in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hypothetical

Suppose we know there is a subset of a[1],a[2],...,a[i] with sum m.

Ask yourself whether the subset includes a[i] or not.

### If answer is No

Then the same subset can be used to show there is a subset of a[1],a[2],...,a[i-1] with sum m.

### If answer is Yes

Then we know that there is a subset (with x,y < i) such that a[x]+a[y]+...+a[i] = m.

Therefore a[x]+a[y]+... = m-a[i]

Therefore there is a subset of a[1],...,a[i-1] with sum m-a[i]

### Conclusion

So we have proved that if v[i,m] is equal to 1, then one or other condition must hold.  (It is also possible for both conditions to hold.)

### Alternative perspective

It may seem more natural to look at this constructively.

Think of all values you can make as a subset of a[1],..,a[i-1].  In your example [3,2,7] can make all the values [0,2,3,5,7,10,12,13].

Then consider what values we can make if we also can include a[i].  This will be the original set of values [0,2,3,5,7,10,12,13] intersected with the set of values with a[i] added [0+1,2+1,3+1,5+1,7+1,10+1,12+1,13+1].

So a value m will be in the new set either if it was in the old set, or if m-a[i] was in the old set.